# What happens when I successfully attack a player's home stronghold?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Each player has a home stronghold, which has a bonus token, which adds combat strength.

The question is - if I attack it and successfully take the territory - what happens? - Is the token discarded? What happens if that player retakes the territory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The token, representing the garrison of the stronghold, is removed once it has been taken by an enemy player.

If the original owner of that territory retakes it, the token is **not** replaced.

Relevant quote from the rule book, page 26

> If a Garrison is defeated in combat (whether defending by itself or
>   with other friendly units), it is permanently removed from the game,
>   regardless of the number of Sword or Fortification icons on House
>   cards played in the combat.